# Applied Power on TVS Diode

Tags: power, diodes, tvs

I need to calculate the Applied power on a TVS Diode, what I know is P=U*I, I am applying 5v voltage on the TVS Diode but I am wondering what should be the Current value? Should I use the Leakage current as it is reverse Biased? also can this be applied on any type of reverse biased diode?

Comment: Why do you need to calculate the applied power? Is it for battery life calculation purposes, or to make sure you do not damage the  TVS diode? Or some other reason? The power is always V*I, as you say, but the dissipation will generally be very low except when a transient voltage causes the diode to operate in Zener mode.

Comment: If you just want to know the actual dissipation during normal operation, you can use the reverse leakage. If you are interested in what happens during transient voltage events, well, it is more complicated.

Comment: Customer, that i'm designing the Circuit for, is asking for applied power on components in normal mode, this is why i need to calculate the power.

Comment: Yeah, I guess use the leakage from the datasheet. Or hook it up to a power supply and measure it. It does vary with temperature. I believe the current has an inverse relationship with temperature near the Zener threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**. You are right.

In simple terms power dissipation is simply the **product** of the applied **reverse voltage** and the **reverse leakage current.**

The reverse leakage current varies *exponentially* with the temperature. Hence the power dissipation will be proportional to the temperature.

[Here](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/50/99/75/c8/f4/54/43/12/DM00044087.pdf/files/DM00044087.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00044087.pdf) is one Example of computing reverse losses in a diode in a typical application.
Another example from one of the TVS diode datasheet from Vishay:

For simplicity, you can take worst case reverse leakage current and reverse voltage to get power dissipation during normal operation.

[image]

Comment: I am not so sure you are right about power. If the temperature effect matters, I suggest the OP find a temperature curve in the datasheet or measure it directly.

Comment: The issue is the temperature coefficient of the  breakdown voltage. For higher voltage TVS's, at least, the breakdown voltage goes up with temperature, not down. It may be the opposite for a 5V TVS. So anyway, I suggest the  OP measure it if it matters.

Comment: @mkeith What i understood is that OP is just trying to measure standby power dissipation of the revere biased diode (in general, as stated in last line of the question)

Comment: Yeah. It is a good answer. But if the OP is on the hook for measuring power at temperatures other than 25C, it may be advisable to dig a little deeper on the temperature effect. That is all I was trying to say in my comment.